# OnClick event not binding/firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slim-lang, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to create a select link that fire all checkbox on the current page but it doesn't work just reloads the page.

#### file_items.js

```
$('a.select-all-current').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e);
  $('input:not(:checked)').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).click();
  });
  return false;
});
```

#### index.html.slim

```
...
.col-lg-6.pull-right.align-right
      .pull-right
        = link_to 'Deselect All', '#', class: 'label'
      .dropdown.col-lg-2.pull-right
        a#selectAllMenu.dropdown-toggle[ data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='true']
          .label.select-all
            = "Select All  "
            span.caret.pull-right
        ul.dropdown-menu[role='menu'  aria-labelledby='selectAllMenu']
          li 
            | SELECT
          li
            hr
          li
            = link_to 'current page', '', class: 'select-all-current'
          li
            = link_to 'all files', '', class: 'select-all-files'
          li
            = link_to 'all untagged files', '', class: 'select-all-untagged'
...
```

Comment: You should call `e.preventDefault()`, not `$(e).preventDefault()`.

Comment: @JohnS Thanks I changed that but it still behaves the same

Comment: @AntarrByrd The JS works now. Is it being wrapped in `$(function() { [code here] });`

Comment: Are you sure $('a.select-all-current') is selecting what you need? Maybe try adding e.stopImmediatePropagation() at the top of your click handler?

Comment: Cool, I've create an answer for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the code in a document ready statement like this.

```
$(function() { 
    $('a.select-all-current').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(e);
      $('input:not(:checked)').each(function(index, element){
        $(element).click();
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```